# NSOutlineView column width

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

ALL,

I have NSOutlineView with 2 columns. This view is sized so that it is wide enough to cover the whole monitor.

The view contains 2 columns. The second column has a fixed width.

Lets say the width of the screen is 1920 and the width of the second column is 100. Then I want the width of the first column to be 1820.
I.e., column_width1 + column_width2 = screen_width and therefore no scrollbar is visible.

What is the easiest way to do it from the code?

(I'm using Objective-C Cocoa API).

TIA!

EDIT:

After trying the suggestions the only thing I could come up with was the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: @Willeke, Why did you remove your answer? I tried it, but got the result showing in the OP screenshot. Could you take a look? I don't have a header in the view - will that be a difference? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _scrnW [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width
#define _col1W _scrnW - 100
#define _col2W 100
```

The following code programmatically creates an NSOutlineView using manual reference counting:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
 NSWindow *window;
}
- (void) buildMenu;
- (void) buildWindow;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void) dealloc {
 [window release];
 [super dealloc];
}

- (void) buildMenu {
 NSMenu *menubar = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
 NSMenuItem *menuBarItem = [[NSMenuItem new] autorelease];
 [menubar addItem:menuBarItem];
 [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
 NSMenu *appMenu = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
 NSMenuItem *quitMenuItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit"
 action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"] autorelease];
 [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
 [menuBarItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
}

- (void) buildWindow {

#define _scrnW [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width
#define _col1W _scrnW - 100
#define _col2W 100
#define _wndW  _scrnW
#define _wndH  550

window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH )
styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];

[window center];
[window setTitle: @"Test window"];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];

// ***** NSScrollView to hold OutlineView ****** //
 NSScrollView *scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 1, 60, _wndW, _wndH - 60 )];
 [scrollView setBorderType:NSBezelBorder];
 [scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
 [scrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:YES];
 [scrollView setAutohidesScrollers:YES];
 [scrollView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];

 // ******* NSOutlineView ******* //
 NSOutlineView *outlineView = [[NSOutlineView alloc] initWithFrame: [scrollView bounds]];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: outlineView];
 [outlineView release];

 // ***** OutlineView Controller ****** //
 // OutlineViewController *myController = [[OutlineViewController alloc] init];
 // [outlineView setDataSource: myController];
 // [outlineView setDelegate: myController];

 // ***** Column one ***** //
 NSTableColumn *colOne = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"Col1"];
 [colOne setEditable: NO];
 [colOne setWidth: _col1W];
 [colOne setMinWidth: _col1W];
 [colOne setMaxWidth: _col1W];
 [[colOne headerCell] setStringValue:@"colOne"];
 [outlineView addTableColumn: colOne];
 // **** Won't see triangles without this ***** //
 [outlineView setOutlineTableColumn:colOne];
 [colOne release];

 // ***** Column two ****** //
 NSTableColumn *colTwo = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"Col2"];
 [colTwo setEditable: NO];
 [colTwo setWidth: _col2W];
 [colTwo setMinWidth: _col2W];
 [colTwo setMaxWidth: _col2W];
 [[colTwo headerCell] setStringValue:@"colTwo"];
 [outlineView addTableColumn: colTwo];
 // **** Won't see triangles without this ***** //
 [outlineView setOutlineTableColumn:colTwo];
 [colTwo release];

 // ***** Embed OutlineView into scroll view **** //
 [scrollView setDocumentView:outlineView];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: scrollView];
 [scrollView release];

 // ***** Quit btn ***** //
 NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 5, 40, 40 )];
 [quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
 [quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
 [quitBtn setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinXMargin];
 [quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];
 [quitBtn release];
}

- (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
 [self buildMenu];
 [self buildWindow];
}

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
}
@end

int main () {
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
 NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[[AppDelegate alloc] init] autorelease];
 [application setDelegate:appDelegate];
 [application run];
 [pool drain];
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?

Comment: @apodidae, I did state that the outline view was covering the full width of the main window. But I was hoping to get a generic answer. It is possible that my requirements will change that window will have some other controls to the left or right of that view. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: @apodidae, it doesn't work. Please see the screenshot in the OP. Thx.

Comment: Of course it works; I wouldn't post it if it didn't work.  Name the file olv.m and then run the demo from Terminal with the following: clang olv.m -framework Cocoa -o olv && ./olv. If your use of it 'doesn't work' then you need to post runnable source code which demonstrates the problem.